# Setear un selectpicker bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Asignar un valor a selectpicker. he intentado hacerlo como dice la [documentación](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerval) pero no me ha funcionado, el punto es que las opciones las recibo directamente de la DB y quiero poder agregar un opción adicional a los registros. es decir que sea como un `<option value="0">Seleccione una categoría...</option>`.

```
$('#idcategoria').selectpicker('val', 'Seleccione la categoría...');
```

Si lo coloco de esta forma me aparece en la primer opción "Nothing selected", y como mencione anteriormente quiero que me aparezca: Seleccione la categoría

**HTML**

```
<select id="idcategoria" name="idcategoria" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

yo lo resolví en el archivo control, así:

```
$rspta = $rutas->select();//Carga variable con funcion select de categoría
echo '<option value="0">seleccione...</option>';
while ($reg = $rspta->fetch_object())//mientras exista respuesta
{
    echo '<option value=' . $reg->idRuta . '>' . $reg->nombreRuta .'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es poner una opción no seleccionable, como una guia, puede ponerlo de la siguiente manera, asignándole las propiedades **disable** y **selected**:

```html
<select id="idcategoria" name="idcategoria" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>

<option disabled selected value="0"> Seleccione la categoría... </option>
<option value="">1</option>
<option value="">2</option>
<option value="">3</option>
</select>
```

Si ademas quieres que no se vea, puedes usar:

```
<option style="display:none">
```

y no se vera cuando abras el select.

Fuente: [Respuesta de SO en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23638053/7291849)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que queerés hacer no se hace asignando un `value`, se hace así:

"noneSelectedText  string  'Nothing selected'
The text that is displayed when a multiple select has no selected options."

```
 $.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.BootstrapVersion = '4';
 $.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.DEFAULTS.noneSelectedText = 'No seleccionaste nada';
 $.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.DEFAULTS.noneResultsText ='No hay concidencias{0}';
```

De esta manera queda seteado para los `select` en tu código.
Realmente es un dolor de cabeza asignar un valor una vez que esta activado el `selectpicker`.

Answer (score 0):

hola solo es agregando esta linea mira

```
 <option disabled="disabled">Seleccione la categoría</option>
```

espero te funcione (:

Comment: ¿Por qué se tiene que agregar esto?